# How can I achieve SSO with cloud servers?

Tags: active-directory, cloud, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I want to be able to achieve SSO with all of our cloud servers so that password management is made a little easier.

We have an On-Premise AD and also an Office365 subscription that comes with Azure etc.

I cannot currently see a way to achieve this but I would like to know if it is possible.

All I am essentially asking is can my users RDP onto the cloud servers we use with credentials that they use to access their Office365 applications?

Comment: your question is broad to be answered in a single SO question. But you may start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-sso) to get an idea.